# How to name Values in array by values in different array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have two arrays:

The first contains unique names of fields in a nested array:

```
[0][0]:Name1
[0][1]:Name2
[0][2]:Name3
etc.
```

The second contains multiple items with values in a nested array like this:

```
[0][0] XYZ
[0][1] XYZA
[0][2] XYZ2
[1][0] XYZaa
[1][1] XYZas
[1][2] XYA
etc
```

What I want to do is to merge it and name it in this way:

```
[0] Name1: XYZ
[0] Name2: XYZA
[0] Name3: XYZ2
[1] Name1: XYZaa
[1] Name2: XYZas
[1] Name3: XYA
```

To achieve this I first attempted the following:

```
var mergedArr = name.concat(data);
```

That works fine, however I believe I can also use lodash to get closer to what I want:

```
_.merge(name, data)
```

and should work fine too.

I was trying to name it by using

```
_.zipObject
```

Yet it doesn't work the way I would like

I was trying few options with zip, zipObject, yet non of it gave me expected output.

Edit1:
how I created arrays:

```
    $("#T1020 tr").each(function(x, z){
    name[x] = [];
    $(this).children('th').each(function(xx, zz){
           name[x][xx] = $(this).text();

      });

})

    $("#T1020 tr").each(function(i, v){
        data[i] = [];
        $(this).children('td').each(function(ii, vv){
            data[i][ii] = $(this).text();

      });
   })
```

Comment: It's pretty unclear (to me at least) what your situation is and what you want. Could you make your first three code samples be valid javascript?

Comment: Added to edit, how I created arrays. So they are a table pretty much, names, contains names, and data is all fields that I scrapped. I would like to name those fields in data by names in name array.

Comment: I just want to point out that your syntax for appending an item to an array (`data[i][ii] = $(this).text();`) strikes me as a little unclear as the index `ii` is not defined at the point where this is called. You might want to consider using `data[i].push( $(this).text() );` instead.

Comment: Thanks, definitely will try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're wanting to zip `array1` and `array2` into a single array where:

- each item of the result array is an object
- the keys of each object are values of `array1[0]`, and
- the values of each key corresponding nested array of `array2`

To produce the following:

```
[
 {
  "name1": "xyz",
  "name2": "xyza",
  "name3": "xyz2"
 },
 {
  "name1": "xyzaa",
  "name2": "xyzas",
  "name3": "xya"
 }
]
```

This can be achieved without lodash; first map each item of `array2` by a function where `array1[0]` is reduced to an object. The reduced object is composed by a key that is the current reduce item, and a value that is taken from the indexed value of the current map item:

```js
const array1 = [
  ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
]

const array2 = [
  ['xyz', 'xyza', 'xyz2'],
  ['xyzaa', 'xyzas', 'xya']
]


const result = array2.map((item) => {

  /* Reduce items of array1[0] to an object
  that corresponds to current item of array2 */
  return array1[0].reduce((obj, value, index) => {

    return { ...obj,
      [value]: item[index]
    };
  }, {});

});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, ' '));
```

Comment: That worked just perfectly, thank you very much for explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the `values` (your `array2`) and take the sub-array from the keys (`array`) using the current index and the `%` operator. This will ensure that if that the keys are taken in a cyclic way (see example with `keys2` and `values2`). Convert to object with `_.zipObject`:

```js
const fn = (keys, values) => values.map((v, i) => _.zipObject(keys[i % keys.length], v))

const keys1 = [['name1', 'name2', 'name3']]
const values1 = [['xyz', 'xyza', 'xyz2'], ['xyzaa', 'xyzas', 'xya']]
const keys2 = [['name1', 'name2', 'name3'], ['name11', 'name12', 'name13']]
const values2 = [['xyz', 'xyza', 'xyz2'], ['xyzaa', 'xyzas', 'xya'], ['abc', 'def', 'hij']]

console.log(fn(keys1, values1))
console.log(fn(keys2, values2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```